# How to transfer unicode text between Java and Dart over Socket?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, unicode

I am trying to exchange Strings between a Java-based server and a Dart(Flutter)-based client. The charset should cover all of unicode, utf8mb4_unicode_ci that is.

In Java, I open the IO streams like:

```
outStream = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Reading / writing is done using `inStream.readLine()` and `outStream.println()`

Results and inputs for these streams are handled as simple Java String objects.

On the Dart(Flutter) client, the IO streams are as follows:

```
Socket socket = Socket.connect(url, port);
Stream<String>? stream = socket?.asBroadcastStream().map(String.fromCharCodes);
```

Here, reading is done through a buffer to allow large packets (since Dart splits larger packets)

```
StringBuffer responseBuffer = StringBuffer();
await for (String packet in stream!) {
    responseBuffer.write(packet);
    if (packet.contains('_')) {
        break;
    }
}
```

And writing is done through `socket.writeln(query)`

Results and inputs for these streams as well are handled as simple Dart String objects.

Now the problem is, whenever I attempt to transmit non ASCII chars, like äöüß (german) or any type of emoji, the result is either ? or the question mark in a box.

What do I need to change, to force both the Java-based server as well as the Dart(Flutter)-based client to handle these Strings as UTF8 strings?

Comment: I don't see where you're converting the incoming stream to UTF8. Perhaps you're missing that step, or just didn't show it.

Comment: I am relatively new to Dart so I dont quite know as much about its encoding of strings and the methods to decode them, but I have searched for quite some time now and couldnt find any helpful information on this. Do you perhaps happen to know the solution?

Comment: `String.fromCharCodes` creates a `String` either from UTF-16 code units or from Unicode code points.  If you want to construct a Dart `String` from UTF-8, you must use [`Utf8Decoder`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-convert/Utf8Decoder-class.html).  Additionally, as explained by [the `Stream.map` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/map.html), you instead should use [`Stream.transform`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/transform.html) in case the the sequence of UTF-8 bytes is not chunked on a codepoint boundary.